# Duvida sobre alinhamento vertical e tableless

Tags: html

O Wikipedia define tableless como:

> Tableless é uma forma de desenvolvimento de sites que não utiliza tabelas para disposição de conteúdo na página sugerido pela W3C , pois defende que os códigos HTML deveriam ser usados para o propósito que foram criados, sendo que tabelas foram criadas para exibir dados tabulares. Para a disposição da página o recomendado seria usar CSS.

Uma coisa que sempre me causa dor de cabeça é fazer alinhamento vertical de elementos. Quanto mais elementos diferentes na mesma linha, mais complicação.

Já pesquisei várias soluções e muita são 'meia-boca'. Porém tem uma que achei bastante satisfatória, é a seguinte:

```css
    .t{display:table;border:1px solid red;}
    .td1,.td2{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;padding:10px;}
```

```html
    <div class="t">
     <div class="tr">
       <div class="td1"><img src="https://www.cdn.renault.com/content/dam/Renault/BR/personal-cars/duster-oroch/packshot/duster-oroch-lateral-passageiro.jpg.ximg.l_4_m.smart.jpg"></div>
       <div class="td2"><p>ESSE É O MEU CARRO</p></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Porém o código acima apenas faz com que as divs se comportem como se fosse uma tabela... O código acima está em desacordo com o conceito de tableless?

Devo evitar esse tipo de implementação???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Porém o código acima apenas faz com que as divs se comportem como se fosse uma tabela... O código acima está em desacordo com o conceito de tableless?

Não foge do conceito de tableless, esse conceito visa muito mais exterminar o antigo modo de desenvolvimento de páginas através da tag  que tinha uma série *colspan*, pouquíssimo css e o pouco que tinha era espalhado no meio da página. Além disso a tag *table* não foi criada para fazer layout.

O exemplo mais famoso que posso mencionar é o [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/). Ele usa em diversos pontos do arquivo de estilo (CSS) o display *table* e *table-cell* em algumas classes como por exemplo:

- input-group
- input-group-btn
- media-body
- media-left
- media-right

Enfim, não se preocupe com isso. O Tableless, como já disse, vem com o intuito de dizer que **a tag deve ser usada para a finalidade dela e não para criar layout**.

> Devo evitar esse tipo de implementação?

Você pode continuar usando, mas sabendo que esse tipo de display não é compatível com todos os browsers e normalmente é utilizado como *fix* no layout. Se você encontrar outra forma de deixar seu layout do jeito que você quer, faça, caso não encontre, mesmo depois de pesquisar na net, utilize sem problemas. Afinal, como já mencionei o [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/) usa e ele é uma referência no que se refere a CSS dentro do padrão atual, inclusive quando se trata de responsividade (que não é assunto desta pergunta, mas vale ressaltar).

Deixei também um artigo bem interessante abaixo sobre [*o anti-herói do layout em CSS "display: table"*](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero).

Espero ter te ajudado.

---

**Somente uma observação:**

Caso esteja com dificuldades na criação do layout, implementa o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) no teu projeto, ele é uma mão na roda e eu gosto bastante de utilizá-lo. Ele tem vários *fix* para diversos browsers e retira alguns padrões chatinhos do navegador.

**Links que podem ajudar**

Recomendo alguns artigos sobre display e o display do tipo table abaixo:

- [CSS-Tricks - Display](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)
- [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
- [O anti-herói do CSS - "display:table"](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)

Answer (score 0):

Adriano,

Mesmo não usando tabela você ainda está pensando "como tabelas" e não deveria ser assim, você precisa pensar na construção de layouts tableless como "blocos". Imagine a construção de um muro, cada bloco terá seu posicionamento relativo aos blocos ao seu redor, mas diferentemente de um muro na web você também pode usar o posicionamento absoluto que permite posicionar um bloco onde você quiser utilizando como referência um elemento pai.

O alinhamento vertical não será problema utilizando atributos css "margin" ou "padding" mas normalmente o alinhamento vertical se dará com a construção do seu site, isto é uma imagem poderá estar abaixo de uma serie de outros elementos como parágrafos, títulos ou até mesmo outras imagens e dessa forma se dará seu alinhamento vertical.

Mas se mesmo assim você quiser ter o controle da distância de um elemento em bloco para outro considere usar "margin" ou "padding", mas eles tem diferença

margin: define a margem de um objeto em relação ao dom (grosseiramente a janela) vale a pena ressaltar que as coordenadas na web iniciam no canto superior esquerdo. O atributo margin afeta a coordenada do elemento em relação ao dom ou ao elemento que ele é filho ou elementos ao redor, por isso você tem o controle das margens (esquerda, direita, superior e inferior).

padding: este é um pouco diferente de margin, pois este não afeta o posicionamento do elemento e sim do conteúdo dentro do elemento, parece confuso mas é muito simples imagine uma div com um paragrafo dentro, alterando o padding (preenchimento) da div eu consigo alterar o posicionamento do conteúdo dentro desse elemento, no caso o parágrafo.

para nunca se confundir entre margin e padding sempre pense "Margin é a margem do elemento e padding o preenchimento desse elemento"

Bom Adriano, essa é uma explicação um pouco longa, mas procurei ser o mais simplista e didático possível, claro que há muitas coisas e detalhes não mencionados bem como uma série de particularidades, mas dada a vastidão da pergunta eu procurei diminuir ao máximo o abismo entre uma pergunta tão abrangente e uma resposta sucinta.

abraço